# Renaming object keys recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a recursive function to rename the key names of an object but I'm unable to figure out how to rename 2 of the keys (problem keys are objects)

I think the problem is where I'm checking for object type but how can I rename the key at that point?

The actual arrays are very large but a cut down version is below.

Any help appreciated.

```
var keys_short = ['ch','d','u','tz'];
var keys_long = ['children','data','user_id','time_zone'];
function refit_keys(o){
    build = {};
    for (var i in o){
        if(typeof(o[i])=="object"){
            o[i] = refit_keys(o[i]);
            build = o;
        }else{
            var ix = keys_short.indexOf(i);
            if(ix!=-1){
                build[keys_long[ix]] = o[keys_short[ix]];
            }
        }
    }
    return build;
}
```

My input looks like this:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "ch":[
        {
            "id":"3",
            "ch":[
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"3",
                "tz":"8.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"45",
            "ch":[
                {
                    "id":"70",
                    "ch":[
                        {
                            "id":"43",
                            "ch":[
                            ],
                            "d":{
                                "u":"43",
                                "tz":"-7.00"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "d":{
                        "u":"70",
                        "tz":"-7.00"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"45",
                "tz":"-7.00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "d":{
        "u":"1",
        "tz":"8.00"
    }
}
```

My output like this:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "ch":[
        {
            "id":"3",
            "ch":[
            ],
            "d":{
                "user_id":"3",
                "time_zone":"8.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"45",
            "ch":[
                {
                    "id":"70",
                    "ch":[
                        {
                            "id":"43",
                            "ch":[
                            ],
                            "d":{
                                "user_id":"43",
                                "time_zone":"-7.00"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "d":{
                        "user_id":"70",
                        "time_zone":"-7.00"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "d":{
                "user_id":"45",
                "time_zone":"-7.00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "d":{
        "user_id":"1",
        "time_zone":"8.00"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a couple of problems there.

One is that you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by failing to declare your `build` variable in the function.

But the logic has issues as well, here's a minimal reworking:

```
var keys_short = ["ch","d","u","tz"];
var keys_long = ["children","data","user_id","time_zone"];
function refit_keys(o){
    var build, key, destKey, ix, value;

    // Only handle non-null objects
    if (o === null || typeof o !== "object") {
        return o;
    }

    // Handle array just by handling their contents
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map(refit_keys);
    }

    // We have a non-array object
    build = {};
    for (key in o) {
        // Get the destination key
        ix = keys_short.indexOf(key);
        destKey = ix === -1 ? key : keys_long[ix];

        // Get the value
        value = o[key];

        // If this is an object, recurse
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = refit_keys(value);
        }

        // Set it on the result using the destination key
        build[destKey] = value;
    }
    return build;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";
var input = {
    "id":"1",
    "ch":[
        {
            "id":"3",
            "ch":[
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"3",
                "tz":"8.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"45",
            "ch":[
                {
                    "id":"70",
                    "ch":[
                        {
                            "id":"43",
                            "ch":[
                            ],
                            "d":{
                                "u":"43",
                                "tz":"-7.00"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "d":{
                        "u":"70",
                        "tz":"-7.00"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"45",
                "tz":"-7.00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "d":{
        "u":"1",
        "tz":"8.00"
    }
};

var keys_short = ["ch","d","u","tz"];
var keys_long = ["children","data","user_id","time_zone"];
function refit_keys(o){
    var build, key, destKey, ix, value;

    // Only handle non-null objects
    if (o === null || typeof o !== "object") {
        return o;
    }

    // Handle array just by handling their contents
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map(refit_keys);
    }

    // We have a non-array object
    build = {};
    for (key in o) {
        // Get the destination key
        ix = keys_short.indexOf(key);
        destKey = ix === -1 ? key : keys_long[ix];

        // Get the value
        value = o[key];

        // If this is an object, recurse
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = refit_keys(value);
        }

        // Set it on the result using the destination key
        build[destKey] = value;
    }
    return build;
}

console.log(refit_keys(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

But rather than parallel arrays, I'd suggest using a mapping, via an object or a `Map`:

```
// Object with no prototype to avoid false matches on `toString` and other built-ins
var mapShortToLong = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    "ch": "children",
    "d":  "data",
    "u":  "user_id",
    "tz": "time_zone"
});
function refit_keys(o){
    var build, key, destKey, value;

    // Only handle non-null objects
    if (o === null || typeof o !== "object") {
        return o;
    }

    // Handle array just by handling their contents
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map(refit_keys);
    }

    build = {};
    for (key in o) {
        // Get the destination key
        destKey = mapShortToLong[key] || key;

        // Get the value
        value = o[key];

        // If this is an object, recurse
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = refit_keys(value);
        }

        // Set it on the result using the destination key
        build[destKey] = value;
    }
    return build;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";
var input = {
    "id":"1",
    "ch":[
        {
            "id":"3",
            "ch":[
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"3",
                "tz":"8.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"45",
            "ch":[
                {
                    "id":"70",
                    "ch":[
                        {
                            "id":"43",
                            "ch":[
                            ],
                            "d":{
                                "u":"43",
                                "tz":"-7.00"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "d":{
                        "u":"70",
                        "tz":"-7.00"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"45",
                "tz":"-7.00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "d":{
        "u":"1",
        "tz":"8.00"
    }
};

// Object with no prototype to avoid false matches on `toString` and other built-ins
var mapShortToLong = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    "ch": "children",
    "d":  "data",
    "u":  "user_id",
    "tz": "time_zone"
});
function refit_keys(o){
    var build, key, destKey, value;

    // Only handle non-null objects
    if (o === null || typeof o !== "object") {
        return o;
    }

    // Handle array just by handling their contents
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map(refit_keys);
    }

    build = {};
    for (key in o) {
        // Get the destination key
        destKey = mapShortToLong[key] || key;

        // Get the value
        value = o[key];

        // If this is an object, recurse
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = refit_keys(value);
        }

        // Set it on the result using the destination key
        build[destKey] = value;
    }
    return build;
}

console.log(refit_keys(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or in modern JavaScript:

```
// Using a `Map` here to provide a `Map` example, but you can ue an object as
// in the previous ones if you prefer if the keys are strings
const mapShortToLong = new Map([
    ["ch", "children"],
    ["d",  "data"],
    ["u",  "user_id"],
    ["tz", "time_zone"],
]);
function refit_keys(o){
    // Only handle non-null objects
    if (o === null || typeof o !== "object") {
        return o;
    }

    // Handle array just by handling their contents
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map(refit_keys);
    }

    const build = {};
    for (const key in o) {
        // Get the destination key
        const destKey = mapShortToLong.get(key) || key;

        // Get the value
        let value = o[key];

        // If this is an object, recurse
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = refit_keys(value);
        }

        // Set it on the result using the destination key
        build[destKey] = value;
    }
    return build;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";
var input = {
    "id":"1",
    "ch":[
        {
            "id":"3",
            "ch":[
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"3",
                "tz":"8.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"45",
            "ch":[
                {
                    "id":"70",
                    "ch":[
                        {
                            "id":"43",
                            "ch":[
                            ],
                            "d":{
                                "u":"43",
                                "tz":"-7.00"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "d":{
                        "u":"70",
                        "tz":"-7.00"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "d":{
                "u":"45",
                "tz":"-7.00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "d":{
        "u":"1",
        "tz":"8.00"
    }
};

// Using a `Map` here to provide a `Map` example, but you can ue an object as
// in the previous ones if you prefer if the keys are strings
const mapShortToLong = new Map([
    ["ch", "children"],
    ["d",  "data"],
    ["u",  "user_id"],
    ["tz", "time_zone"],
]);
function refit_keys(o){
    // Only handle non-null objects
    if (o === null || typeof o !== "object") {
        return o;
    }

    // Handle array just by handling their contents
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map(refit_keys);
    }

    const build = {};
    for (const key in o) {
        // Get the destination key
        const destKey = mapShortToLong.get(key) || key;

        // Get the value
        let value = o[key];

        // If this is an object, recurse
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            value = refit_keys(value);
        }

        // Set it on the result using the destination key
        build[destKey] = value;
    }
    return build;
}

console.log(refit_keys(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Above and beyond. Works perfectly, taught me something and found a better method

Comment: Any proof that seconf method is better/faster?

Comment: @benoror: I don't think I claimed it was better or faster, but parallel arrays are, in general, a maintenance issue. Too easy to modify one and not the other. Much harder to mistakenly modify *half* of a property initializer. ;-)

Comment: @PanMan - Thanks! I've fixed that and generally updated a bit.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but I was looking for a nice short implementation that also *deals with arrays* (the previous answer doesn't), so I decided to post my generic ES6 implementation, as it may help some folks:

```
function deepMapKeys(originalObject, callback) {
  if (typeof originalObject !== 'object') {
    return originalObject
  }

  return Object.keys(originalObject || {}).reduce((newObject, key) => {
    const newKey = callback(key)
    const originalValue = originalObject[key]
    let newValue = originalValue
    if (Array.isArray(originalValue)) {
      newValue = originalValue.map(item => deepMapKeys(item, callback))
    } else if (typeof originalValue === 'object') {
      newValue = deepMapKeys(originalValue, callback)
    }
    return {
      ...newObject,
      [newKey]: newValue,
    }
  }, {})
}
```

For the case in question, the call would be:

```
deepMapKeys(inputObject, key => (keys_long[keys_short.indexOf(key)] || key))
```

That being said, if you can use npm, there are several packages out there (here's [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-map-keys), [another](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/deep-rename-keys)..)

Comment: Thanks for the links to the packages.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problem could be that the variable `build` is actually a global variable. Hence, it contains only the result of the first depth in the recursion.

Adding a `var` before `build` should solve part of the problem.

Comment: No, that's not the only problem. It *is* a problem, it's just not the only one.

Answer (score 2):

More concise implementation of the recursive mapping function for object keys:

```
const objectRecursiveKeyMap = (obj, fn) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    const getValue = v =>
      (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) ? objectRecursiveKeyMap(v, fn) : v

    return [fn(key), Array.isArray(value)
      ? value.map(val => getValue(val))
      : getValue(value)]
  }))
```

Using example:

```
objectRecursiveKeyMap(obj, key => key.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score -1):

I Like that approach. But I stumbled upon this:

you call it like: `deepMapKeys({testValue:["justString"]}, key => (key));`

returnValue contains:

```
{0: "j", 1: "u", 2: "s", 3: "t", 4: "S", 5: "t", 6: "r", 7: "i", 8: "n", 9: "g"}
```

length: 1

Will say, it converts my string into an array.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @Chris H. , I've updated the answer to fix the use case. You should just comment on my answer directly, cause this is not an answer to the question, so it's confusing. Plus, I don't get any notification (I've noticed your feedback by accident), unless you comment on the answer. Cheers

Comment: It would be best for this to be removed, since it is not an answer to the question.