# how to rename the object key in nested array of object in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I need to rename the object key name dynamically in a nested array of object JavaScript, I had tried with this code. This also I got from Stack Overflow only but this is not working that means it checking first level only not doing deep replacing.

```
const node = {
  'id': 'de603a3e',
  'name': 'erewr',
  'subGroups': [
     {
        'id': '83d7c7e4',
        'name': 'dfds',
        'subGroups': [ ]
     },
     {
        'id': '050cde96',
        'name': 'tetwet',
        'subGroups': [ ]
     },
     {
        'id': 'd67cc4e8',
        'name': 'wewqe',
        'subGroups': [
           {
              'id': '553c301d',
              'name': 'ewqe',
              'subGroups': [

              ]
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        'id': '5d5ae5f2',
        'name': 'rwq',
        'subGroups': [
           {
              'id': 'ff29ad54',
              'name': 'wqe',
              'subGroups': [

              ]
           },
           {
              'id': '5d013943',
              'name': 'weqe',
              'subGroups': [

              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}

console.log(renameKey(node, { subGroups: 'subordinates' }))

renameKey(obj, keysMap) { 
    return transform(obj, function(result, value, key) { 
      const currentKey = keysMap[key] || key; 
      result[currentKey] = isObject(value) ? this.renameKey(value, keysMap) : value; 
    });
  }
```

I am using this code in TypeScript. 
**note** : `transform` and `isObject` are lodash

I am getting error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceKeysDeep' of undefined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming object keys recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752516/renaming-object-keys-recursively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
function renameKeys(node, keysMaps) {
    if(!isObject(node)) return node
    if(Array.isArray(node)) return node.map(item => renameKeys(item, keysMaps))

    return Object.entries(node).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
        const newKey = keysMaps[key] || key;
        return {
            ...result,
            [newKey]: renameKeys(value, keysMaps)

        };
    }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const node = {
  'id': 'de603a3e',
  'name': 'erewr',
  'subGroups': [
     {
        'id': '83d7c7e4',
        'name': 'dfds',
        'subGroups': [ ]
     },
     {
        'id': '050cde96',
        'name': 'tetwet',
        'subGroups': [ ]
     },
     {
        'id': 'd67cc4e8',
        'name': 'wewqe',
        'subGroups': [
           {
              'id': '553c301d',
              'name': 'ewqe',
              'subGroups': [

              ]
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        'id': '5d5ae5f2',
        'name': 'rwq',
        'subGroups': [
           {
              'id': 'ff29ad54',
              'name': 'wqe',
              'subGroups': [

              ]
           },
           {
              'id': '5d013943',
              'name': 'weqe',
              'subGroups': [

              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}

console.log(renameKey(node, { subGroups: 'subordinates' }))

function renameKey(obj, keysMap) { 
    return _.transform(obj, function(result, value, key) { 
      const currentKey = keysMap[key] || key; 
      result[currentKey] = _.isObject(value) ? renameKey(value, keysMap) : value; 
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this only I added previously it not working for me. this the solution they gave previously

Comment: This is edit on ur original code. renameKey was not prefixed with function and in recursion it was calling with this.renameKey. It would be renameKey only. The above code works fine without error if you run the snippet.