# I want to create a function that return a tree from a array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects, I want to rename the keys from "filename" to "name" and "files" to "children" and also want to remove other key value pairs from each level.
Input:

```
 {
"node": [
    {
        "nodeName": "Clothes",
        "nodePath": "3324",
        "readablePath": "Clothes",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "nodeName": "someName",
                "nodePath": "3324-009",
                "readablePath": "Clothes-someName"
            },
            {
                "nodeName": "DF",
                "nodePath": "3324-7F20",
                "readablePath": "Clothes-DF",
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "nodeName": "LP",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F20-6F05",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-DF-LP"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeName": "YA",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F20-6F07",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-DF-YA"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeName": "Kc",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F20-6F20",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-DF-Kc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "nodeName": "Name2",
                "nodePath": "3324-7F10",
                "readablePath": "Clothes-Name2",
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "nodeName": "YY",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F10-6F43",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-Name2-YY"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeName": "TT",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F10-6F4A",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-Name2-TT"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeName": "TET",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F10-6F3B",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-Name2-TET"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeName": "WTT",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F10-6F4A",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-Name2-WTT"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeName": "OET",
                        "nodePath": "3324-7F10-6F3B",
                        "readablePath": "Clothes-Name2-OET"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
"name": [
    {
        "name": "Clothes",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "someName",
            },
            {
                "name": "DF",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "LP",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "YA",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Kc",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Name2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "YY",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "TT",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "TET",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WTT",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "OET",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

I have tried using recursive function for creating a function which can return a tree but not able to achieve this. I want to create a reusable function that I can reuse.

I have created a function

```js
function renameObject(object) {
  let data = []
  Object
      .entries(object)
      .forEach(([k, v]) => {
          if (v && typeof v === Array)
              renameObject(v);
          if (k=="nodeName") {
            data.push({name: v})
          }
      });
  return object;
}
```

Anyone know of a good way to handle this? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you're just renaming keys and leaving some out; a simple `map` call would do that. Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried, and any research you've done into the matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming object keys recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752516/renaming-object-keys-recursively)

Comment: Yes, I want to rename the keys of filename to name and files to children but also removing other key value pairs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The input structure does not have a key "filename" nor "files"? Did you mean "nodeName" and "nodes"? Although you say that you have given it a try yourself, there is no proof that you actually put some time into it. Adding you current attempt to the question shows us that you actually have given it a fair try. It also let us point out where you went wrong, thus helping you learn. Rather than just providing code that works without you learning what you did wrong.

Comment: Yes I mean nodes and nodeName. I have updated my post and added what i have tried, i was pushing new object whenever i am getting the key nodeName but its not the correct way as i am not pushing the children in place of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better and more optimized solutions for this, but here is the simple answer that you can use. basically, you create a new object and check if there is `nodes` property inside of that object, and call the same function again. this will format your data no matter how many layers of `nodes` you have.

```
const input = {
  node: [
    {
      nodeName: 'Clothes',
      nodePath: '3324',
      readablePath: 'Clothes',
      nodes: [
        {
          nodeName: 'someName',
          nodePath: '3324-009',
          readablePath: 'Clothes-someName',
        },
        {
          nodeName: 'DF',
          nodePath: '3324-7F20',
          readablePath: 'Clothes-DF',
          nodes: [
            {
              nodeName: 'LP',
              nodePath: '3324-7F20-6F05',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-DF-LP',
            },
            {
              nodeName: 'YA',
              nodePath: '3324-7F20-6F07',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-DF-YA',
            },
            {
              nodeName: 'Kc',
              nodePath: '3324-7F20-6F20',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-DF-Kc',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          nodeName: 'Name2',
          nodePath: '3324-7F10',
          readablePath: 'Clothes-Name2',
          nodes: [
            {
              nodeName: 'YY',
              nodePath: '3324-7F10-6F43',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-Name2-YY',
            },
            {
              nodeName: 'TT',
              nodePath: '3324-7F10-6F4A',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-Name2-TT',
            },
            {
              nodeName: 'TET',
              nodePath: '3324-7F10-6F3B',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-Name2-TET',
            },
            {
              nodeName: 'WTT',
              nodePath: '3324-7F10-6F4A',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-Name2-WTT',
            },
            {
              nodeName: 'OET',
              nodePath: '3324-7F10-6F3B',
              readablePath: 'Clothes-Name2-OET',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}

function makeTree(data) {
  const newData = []

  data.forEach((node) => {
    const formattedNode = {
      name: node.nodeName,
    }

    if (node.nodes && node.nodes.length > 0) {
      formattedNode.children = makeTree(node.nodes)
    }

    newData.push(formattedNode)
  })

  return newData
}

const formatted = { name: makeTree(input.node) } // input is your data
console.log(JSON.stringify(formatted, null, 2))
```